# Removing specific elements from matrix

Tags: matlab

I want to remove a (*****) asterisk from my matrix and write out that matrix to a text file and the remaining elements will be concatenated to each other without a space or any kind of delimiters. I wrote this code

```
for b = 1 : length(out7num_r7_nt_back)
    if ~(out7num_r7_nt_back(b) == '*')
        out7num_r7_back(b) = '';
    end
end
disp(out7num_r7_nt_back);
dlmwrite('my_data.txt',out7num_r7_nt_back, '');
```

I got this error message:

> > ???  Index of element to remove exceeds matrix dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a vectorized boolean index, replacing the loop as follows:

```
out7num_r7_nt_back = out7num_r7_nt_back(out7num_r7_nt_back(b) ~= '*');
```

That should be much faster as well.

Answer (score 0):

Value of upper bound of `for` loop (`length(out7num_r7_nt_back)`) gets evaluated only ***once***!

Say you have `'*ab'` in a variable. Loop will count to 3 (length of variable). Inside the loop when program erases `'*'`, you'll get `'ab'` which is of length 2. Since loop is iterating to  3, program will try to access `out7num_r7_nt_back(3)` which is *out of bounds*.

You could remove characters while going backwards:

```
...
for b = length(out7num_r7_nt_back) : -1 : 1
...
```

But you should prefer vectorized approach because it's faster and cleaner to write.